# Find nested HTML value in jquery

Tags: html, jquery, selector

I am a total noob in jquery but have an issue to fix in a project.

I have an html file constructed as follows:

```
<div id="mainPromoContainer">
    <div ...
        <div ...
            <div data-promoid="1234" class="promo"
```

What I need to do is to find a way to get the `data-promoid` value which is dynamic depending on what the page has loaded.

What I tried so far without any luck (sorry if this is stupid):

```
const id = $a.closest('.promo').data("promoid");
```

or

```
const id = $("#mainPromoContainer").get(0) ... then do stuff with the result
```

How would you do it? Thanks

Comment: `$("#mainPromoContainer").find(".promo").data("promoid")` ?

Comment: Why you re-define `id` if it's const?

Comment: @Justinas I was just giving examples about how I tried to get the id, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Can you show full structure? How much `.promo` and how much `data-promoid` there is on page (one or more). What exactly is `$a`? Because if one, then you can simply do `$('.promo').data('promoid')`

Comment: @Justinas There should be a single element with a class of `.promo` and with a `data-promoid` value inside `#mainPromoContainer`, hence why I was trying to get the closest to that div.

Comment: Note that "closest" in javascript terms means "closest parent" *not* a child element.   It's a specific term (like "parent")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var elem = $('#mainPromoContainer .promo');
console.log(elem.data("promoid"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainPromoContainer">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div data-promoid="1234" class="promo">some text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using two separate selectors?

Comment: @Sean `$('.promo', '#mainPromoContainer')` is equivalent to `$('#mainPromoContainer').find('.promo')`, which already uses two selectors. The only difference is that this is shorter.

Comment: @Spectric surely `$("#mainPromoContainer .promo")` is even "shorter"?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jQuery to run through all children of your top div, and pull out the data value associated with your ‘.promo’ class:

```
id = $("#mainPromoContainer")
.children()
  .find(".promo")
    .data("promoid")

alert(id)
```

Of course you could just pull the data from the ‘promo’ class directly, so not sure exactly what the issue is.